# java.io.IOException: Not a valid BCFile

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

when i run "yarn logs -applicationId application_1438080928000_6932", appear this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Not a valid BCFile.
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.file.tfile.BCFile$Magic.readAndVerify(BCFile.java:927)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.file.tfile.BCFile$Reader.<init>(BCFile.java:628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.file.tfile.TFile$Reader.<init>(TFile.java:804)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.logaggregation.AggregatedLogFormat$LogReader.<init>(AggregatedLogFormat.java:358)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.logaggregation.LogCLIHelpers.dumpAllContainersLogs(LogCLIHelpers.java:122)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.cli.LogsCLI.run(LogsCLI.java:137)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.cli.LogsCLI.main(LogsCLI.java:199)
```

can anyone give some help?

Comment: It seems your logs are not getting stored in BCFile (Block Compressed File)  format. Hence the error is occurring.

Comment: What is the value of property "yarn.nodemanager.log-aggregation.compression-type" in your yarn-site.xml?

Comment: Thank you @ManjunathBallur, i used the default value "none"

Comment: Did changing this value fix your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I get this error if I try to read the logs directly after killing the job. I would say give it a min at tops then attempt to read the logs again.

Answer (score 0):

In HDP environment if anybody gets this error this while parsing the container logs manually using some TFile reader, this answer might help...

In HDP, `yarn.log-aggregation.file-formats`'s default value is `IndexedFormat,TFile`
So it will aggregate the logs in indexed file format only in `/app-logs/<user>/logs-ifile`

Remove the IndexedFile value for the `yarn.log-aggregation.file-formats` property. Only give `TFile` format.
The logs will get aggregated in `/app-logs/<user>/logs`

Comment: default value is TFile

Comment: I have specifically mentioned that the default value is on HDP cluster only. I know that in normal yarn-site.xml the default value is TFile only. I have cross verified once by creating a new hdp sandbox in Virtualbox. Default value of yarn.log-aggregation.file-formats is "IndexedFormat,TFile" only.