# yarn logs throws an error of "not valid bcfile"

Tags: hadoop-yarn, hdp

HDP version: 3.1.0.78, using ambari 2.7.3 to install.
yarn version: 3.1.1

The application is finished with failed status.

Here is the complete log:

```
yarn logs -applicationId application_1565920695836_0005 
19/08/16 11:49:57 INFO client.AHSProxy: Connecting to Application History server at dn1003.jja.bigo/10.221.117.44:10300
Not a valid BCFile.
Can not find any log file matching the pattern: [ALL] for the application: application_1565920695836_0005
Can not find the logs for the application: application_1565920695836_0005 with the appOwner: hadoop
```

Thanks for your reply.

UPDATE:
After using debug with export YARN_ROOT_LOGGER="DEBUG,console", it says "/data1/app-logs/hadoop/logs/application_1566555356033_0034/meta" is not valid bcfile.

Comment: Did you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34247528/java-io-ioexception-not-a-valid-bcfile?

Comment: @tk421  yes, but it does not work.

Comment: Hi @zhanglistar, we are facing similar issue. did you find a solution?

Comment: @VasanthSubramanian Sorry for the reply. I forgot the things to do.